# Video does not autoplaying in Samsung tab2

Tags: video

I have a video tag in html. I want it to automatically play when the app start but i'd tried different code but still it does not auto playing. This are the codes I've tried so far.

```
<video id = "vid" width="320" height="240" controls autoplay="autoplay">
<video id = "vid" width="320" height="240" controls autoplay="true">
 <video id = "vid" width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
```

I also create a trigger that every time the application load it will play the video but still it does not work.

```
var myVid = document.getElementById("vid").play();

 $('#vid).trigger('play');
 $('#vid').play();
 myVid.autoplay=true;
 myVid.load();
```

Can anyone please help me with auto playing a video .Thank you